# How to rotate a Line or an image from its bottom to 180 degree

Tags: html, css, animation

i have this code which is rotating the hr (a line) from middle, i want to rotate that Line from it's bottom

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#myDIV {
    margin: auto;
   width: 50px;
    background-color: coral;
    color: white;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: mymove 5s infinite;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    50% {-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes mymove {
    50% {transform: rotate(180deg);}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Gradually rotate the DIV element 180 degrees, and back:<p>
<div id="myDIV">
<hr>
</div>
```

how to rotate a line or an image from its bottom just like a Dial whose niddle do rotate

Comment: You should use keyframes property "transform-origin".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it.

```
#myDIV {
    margin: auto;
   width: 50px;
    background-color: coral;
    color: white;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: mymove 5s infinite;
    transform-origin: top left;
}


@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    50% {-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);}

}

@keyframes mymove {
    50% {transform: rotate(180deg);}
}
```

and change transform-origin value according your need, it can be numeric.

Comment: Perfect solution in short time.